# How to get particular character position from string using C#

Tags: c#

This is very basic question but I am not able to find the position of a particular character. For example:

```
string a = "ABCDE";
```

I want the position of "E" from above string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var pos = a.IndexOf('E');
```